# How to revert a function definition in CMake?

Tags: cmake

CMake allows masking any function like this

```
function(add_executable)
   #...custom code, that may use _add_executable(${ARGN}) to call the original function
endfunction()
```

But it seems that once CMake parsed that function definition, it set in global CMake scope and nesting of function definitions is not supported:

```
function(echo)
    message(STATUS "Original function")
endfunction()

echo() #Original function
function(nesting)
    function(echo)
        message(STATUS "Overwritten function")
#       _echo() # Original function
    endfunction()
    echo() #Overwritten function
endfunction()
echo() #Still Overwritten function, expected Original function
```

It will also not work if you `include` the new definition, or even if you define it in CMakeLists added by `add_subdirectory`. Using macros also does not help:

```
macro(echo) 
    _echo(${ARGN})
endmacro(echo)
echo() #Still Overwritten function, but now even _echo() is overwritten
```

Is there any way to revert the old meaning of the function?

Answer (score 0):

Here is one walkaround I found. It is not a true answer, but it works.

```
function(echo)
    message(STATUS "Original function")
endfunction()

echo() #Original function

function(echo)
    if(__ECHO_BEHAVIORAL_SWITCH)
        message(STATUS "Overwritten function")
    else()
        _echo()
    endif()
endfunction()

function(nesting)
    set(__ECHO_BEHAVIORAL_SWITCH 1)
    echo() #Overwritten function
endfunction()

nesting() #Overwritten function

echo() #Original function
```

It does not revert the definition of the function, but rather bounds the behaviour of the overwritten function to the external variable, that may be cached inside functions or `add_subdirectory` just like I expected.